# Crystal Report linked subreport parameter not working properly

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a main report with one group, `part_id`, that contains a subreport in the group header.  There are two linked parameters in the *subreport*.  One is `part_id`, same as the group in the main, and the other is `stores_code`.  The `part_id` parameter is working properly, but the `stores_code` parameter is not.  If a `stores_code` is chosen, then it works, but if no `stores_code` is chosen, then the subreport only returns one record.  I was expecting that it would return all `stores_code` *for that* `part_id`.  Is this because the *subreport* is in the *group header*?  If I remove the link to *stores_code*, then all of the records show up in the subreport, but then I have the opposite problem.  If the user chooses a specific `stores_code`, the subreport still shows all records.

My research led me to believe I need to change the settings of my parameter to `allow multiple and/or to make it optional and/or give it a default and/or allow null values for the parameter`.  However, I am using parameters automatically created by Crystal when the subreport links are added. When you right-click on these parameters the edit option is not available.  So I figure I need to make my own parameters, change the settings, and link to them instead.  However, when I create my own parameters and link to them, the `select data based on subreport field` option is not available.

To make this even more unlcear, these report are run from a third party application.  The selection of `part_id` and `stores_code` is made inside this application.  It is kind of a black-box in that I don't actually have `part_id` and `stores_code` parameters in the main report.  The application takes care of the selection, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: In the subreport, how is the {stores_code} parameter used? Is it a stored procedure parameter or is it used in the record selection formula?

Comment: It is used in the selection formula.  Crystal adds it with something like {?Pm-Param2} = {field2}.  I changed "=" to "IN", but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're displaying the subreport in the 'part_id' group header, the only field you can count on being reliably available is 'part_id'. If there are multiple 'stores_code's in each group, only the *first* record's 'stores_code' of the group will be passed to the subreport. This goes for all other data in the record, also.

If you want to filter the entire report based on certain 'stores_code's via user parameter then you'll need to pass the main report's parameter values to the subreport and do the filtering there.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.  I think you are right, but I don't have access to the main reports parameter values.  There is no selection formula in the main report.  I think the application just adds the selection to the query that is sent to the db.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up unlinking the second parameter, and adding an "ALL" option for it and adjusting the selection formula accordingly.  Similar to this example:

http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/24/crystal-reports-optional-multi-select-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

There are quirks with Crystal Report. Before you re-import sub-reports, it's safer to unlink all parameters first. After re-import, you can link all fields. Otherwise you run into weird issues.